# Adjective to describe very abusive language or nature

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, british-english

I would like to know appropriate adjective(s) to describe a person's abusive language or nature used describe swearing at somebody.

**Edit:** I want a more British and formal English. Something that can be used in formal writing like *opprobrious*.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What's insufficient about “abusive”?

Comment: Rude. Rude. Rude.?

Comment: "Gutter language"

Comment: You need to explain what exactly do you need and why *abusive* is not "appropriate" to describe a person.

Comment: You need to give more details. The only content words you have are 'abusive' and 'swearing at'. Do you mean when someone is yelling at you and using foul language to do so?

Comment: _Acrimonious_ (I have heard it applied to racial slurs)

Comment: How can the question be classed as "unclear"? I fully understand what the OP is asking, and I'm not a genius. Why is his request different from any of the "single-word-requests" that populate the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**scurrilous**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/scurrilous) 
Definition:

> **1. a** : using or given to coarse language **b** : vulgar and evil <*scurrilous
>   imposters who used a religious exterior to rob poor people* — Edwin
>   Benson>
>
> **2** : containing obscenities, abuse, or slander < scurrilous accusations >

An adjective which is appropriate for formal writing as you asked for but carries the risk of alienating your reader(s). It's not a common adjective, I only know it because its origins are Latin and I can speak Italian, ([*scurrile*](http://www.wordreference.com/iten/scurrile)) so your reader might have to get up from his or her chair and google it, in order to understand your written piece. Is this what you really want? If, however, your reader is learned but you use the word inappropriately and within the wrong context, you risk appearing like a fool.

What is wrong with *abusive*, *violent*, *aggressive*, or *hostile*? All these adjectives are understood by the majority of English speaking people. All convey the meaning of aggressive, nasty, vulgar behaviour and speech. If you are still not convinced look at the Ngram Viewer chart below.

[image: google Ngram Viewer]

Link: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scurrilous%2Cabusive%2Cvituperative%2Cfoul-mouthed%2Cvulgar%2Chostile%2Cviolent&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=

**Addendum** In part because I was curious, in part because I love playing around with  Google Ngram; I selected the most obscure suggestions users submitted (excluding *thersitical* which for Ngram does not exist!) and compared their results with *abusive*. Predictably, *abusive* is the clear winner, but it is surprising nevertheless the huge leap it made in the mid-1980's.

[image: Ngram viewer, "abusive" wins]

Comment: Very informative. Have to mark your's as answer.

Comment: Oh, I'm glad you found it useful.

Comment: How about `Horrendous`?

Comment: No, horrendous doesn't describe abusive, violent language as you requested. We use horrendous in different contexts. The ones suggested to you all mean to some degree, violent and "bad".

Answer (score 3):

You could use *[vituperative](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vituperative?view=uk)*

> bitter and abusive: *a vituperative outburst*

The noun form is *[vituperation](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/vituperative)*

> abusive language or venomous censure

Answer (score 1):

For informal use, you could try *[potty-mouth](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/potty+mouth)*:-

> and toilet mouth
>
> n.  someone who uses obscene or profane language in most social
>   settings. (Also a term of address.) : That potty mouth is offending
>   people again. ,  Hey, toilet mouth! Watch your language!

If you are feeling in a more literary mood, *[thersitical](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thersitical)* could be what you are looking for:-

> (Literary & Literary Critical Terms) (Rare) abusive and loud

Edit: perhaps *[foul-mouthed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/foul+mouth)* would be a suitable slightly more formal but not too obscure term:-

> adj given to using obscene, abusive, or blasphemous language

Comment: I'm looking for some formal language. I want use it in some writing. I cannot use `potty-mouth`.

Comment: @SohamDasgupta Please clarify the question itself: don't add comments as they are ephemeral (and, in this case, on an answer, which probably won't help other people who read the question).

Answer (score 1):

Such a person could be described as vulgar or coarse, or if their speech is particularly angry or aggressive, it might be said to be a foul-mouthed tirade.